# How to make chrome recognize a new device after copying .config/google-chrome folder?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I recently installed linux on a new laptop. And I copied the ~/.config/google-chrome folder from my old laptop to the new laptop to duplicate previous settings. But the problem is now the two devices seem to be recognized as the same at settings->recent tabs->Other devices, which I need to access webpages that I browsed on the other devices sometimes. Is there a convenient solution to make the devices separate in that recent tab menu? I don' t want to clear the config folder.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Chrome's built in settings manager? If you sign in to chrome on a new machine it automatically imports all settings.

Comment: Can you add more information on how to do this?

Comment: I already signed in. Because I copied the config folder, I didn' t need to sign in again. I' m not sure if I re-sign in, it will recognize it as a new device. I will try later.

Comment: @chipperyman573 If you go to the chrome settings, there is an option to sign in and sync your account. This will copy all your settings to the computer/phone you're using if you login elsewhere.